# GraphQL query Post with Python Request

Tags: python, json, post, request, graphql

I've been trying to Post Request with Python to scrape some json data from a site. I have no experience with GraphQL, but I think this site is built with it. So anyways, the problem is even if I request it with the POST method, it keeps returning me a "GRAPHQL_PARSE_FAILED" (I'll post the result below). I'm guessing it's because there's a 'downwards arrow with corner leftwards' which is contained in my query. Since the message says it can't parse '\u21B5'.

Here's the code.

```
self.API_URL = 'https://pcmap-api.place.naver.com/graphql'

def get_location_info(self, query, start):
    header = {
        'authority': 'pcmap-api.place.naver.com',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36'
    }

    query = """
    {
        "query getRestaurants($input: RestaurantsInput, $isNmap: Boolean!, $isBounds: Boolean!) {↵  restaurants(input: $input) {↵    total↵    items {↵      ...RestaurantItemFields↵      easyOrder {↵        easyOrderId↵        easyOrderCid↵        businessHours {↵          weekday {↵            start↵            end↵            __typename↵          }↵          weekend {↵            start↵            end↵            __typename↵          }↵          __typename↵        }↵        __typename↵      }↵      baemin {↵        businessHours {↵          deliveryTime {↵            start↵            end↵            __typename↵          }↵          closeDate {↵            start↵            end↵            __typename↵          }↵          temporaryCloseDate {↵            start↵            end↵            __typename↵          }↵          __typename↵        }↵        __typename↵      }↵      yogiyo {↵        businessHours {↵          actualDeliveryTime {↵            start↵            end↵            __typename↵          }↵          bizHours {↵            start↵            end↵            __typename↵          }↵          __typename↵        }↵        __typename↵      }↵      __typename↵    }↵    nlu {↵      ...NluFields↵      __typename↵    }↵    brand {↵      name↵      isBrand↵      type↵      menus {↵        order↵        id↵        images {↵          url↵          desc↵          __typename↵        }↵        name↵        desc↵        price↵        isRepresentative↵        detailUrl↵        orderType↵        catalogId↵        source↵        menuId↵        nutrients↵        allergies↵        __typename↵      }↵      __typename↵    }↵    optionsForMap @include(if: $isBounds) {↵      maxZoom↵      minZoom↵      includeMyLocation↵      maxIncludePoiCount↵      center↵      spotId↵      __typename↵    }↵    __typename↵  }↵}↵↵fragment RestaurantItemFields on RestaurantSummary {↵  id↵  dbType↵  name↵  businessCategory↵  category↵  description↵  hasBooking↵  hasNPay↵  x↵  y↵  distance↵  imageUrl↵  imageUrls↵  imageCount↵  phone↵  virtualPhone↵  routeUrl↵  streetPanorama {↵    id↵    pan↵    tilt↵    lat↵    lon↵    __typename↵  }↵  roadAddress↵  address↵  commonAddress↵  blogCafeReviewCount↵  bookingReviewCount↵  totalReviewCount↵  bookingReviewScore↵  bookingUrl↵  bookingBusinessId↵  talktalkUrl↵  options↵  promotionTitle↵  agencyId↵  businessHours↵  microReview↵  tags↵  priceCategory↵  broadcastInfo {↵    program↵    date↵    menu↵    __typename↵  }↵  michelinGuide {↵    year↵    star↵    comment↵    url↵    hasGrade↵    isBib↵    alternateText↵    __typename↵  }↵  broadcasts {↵    program↵    menu↵    episode↵    broadcast_date↵    __typename↵  }↵  tvcastId↵  naverBookingCategory↵  saveCount↵  uniqueBroadcasts↵  isDelivery↵  markerLabel @include(if: $isNmap) {↵    text↵    style↵    __typename↵  }↵  imageMarker @include(if: $isNmap) {↵    marker↵    markerSelected↵    __typename↵  }↵  isTableOrder↵  isPreOrder↵  isTakeOut↵  bookingDisplayName↵  bookingVisitId↵  bookingPickupId↵  popularMenuImages {↵    name↵    price↵    bookingCount↵    menuUrl↵    menuListUrl↵    imageUrl↵    isPopular↵    usePanoramaImage↵    __typename↵  }↵  visitorReviewCount↵  visitorReviewScore↵  detailCid {↵    c0↵    c1↵    c2↵    c3↵    __typename↵  }↵  streetPanorama {↵    id↵    pan↵    tilt↵    lat↵    lon↵    __typename↵  }↵  __typename↵}↵↵fragment NluFields on Nlu {↵  queryType↵  user {↵    gender↵    __typename↵  }↵  queryResult {↵    ptn0↵    ptn1↵    region↵    spot↵    tradeName↵    service↵    selectedRegion {↵      name↵      index↵      x↵      y↵      __typename↵    }↵    selectedRegionIndex↵    otherRegions {↵      name↵      index↵      __typename↵    }↵    property↵    keyword↵    queryType↵    nluQuery↵    businessType↵    cid↵    branch↵    franchise↵    titleKeyword↵    location {↵      x↵      y↵      default↵      longitude↵      latitude↵      dong↵      si↵      __typename↵    }↵    noRegionQuery↵    priority↵    showLocationBarFlag↵    themeId↵    filterBooking↵    repRegion↵    repSpot↵    dbQuery {↵      isDefault↵      name↵      type↵      getType↵      useFilter↵      hasComponents↵      __typename↵    }↵    type↵    category↵    __typename↵  }↵  __typename↵}↵"
    }
    """ 

    data = {
        'operationName': "getRestaurants",
        'query': query,
        'variables': {'input': {
            'deviceType': "pcmap",
            'display': "50",
            'isNmap': "false",
            'query': query,
            'start': start
        },
        'isBound': 'true',
        'isNmap': 'false'
        }
    }
    r = requests.post(self.API_URL, headers=header, json=data).json()
```

As you can see in the query, it has the arrow that GraphQL can't parse. I'm guessing that I have to convert the "query" into some kind that GraphQL can understand. But it's kinda frustrating since I just copied and pasted what Request Payload has just shown. I placed query outside of the data parameter, because it seemed too messy.

Here's the result.

```
{
"errors": [
    {
        "extensions": {
            "code": "GRAPHQL_PARSE_FAILED"
        },
        "locations": [
            {
                "column": 89,
                "line": 1
            }
        ],
        "message": "Syntax Error: Cannot parse the unexpected character \"\\u21B5\".",
        "status": 500
    }
]
```

}

I really would appreciate it you can think of a way to solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your `query` variable should be without curly braces AND you should replace all the '↵' symbols with '\n':

```py
query = "query getRestaurants($input: RestaurantsInput, $isNmap: Boolean!, $isBounds: Boolean!) {\n  restaurants(input: $input) {\n    total\n    items {\n      ...RestaurantItemFields\n      easyOrder {\n        easyOrderId\n        easyOrderCid\n        businessHours {\n          weekday {\n            start\n            end\n            __typename\n          }\n          weekend {\n            start\n            end\n            __typename\n          }\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      baemin {\n        businessHours {\n          deliveryTime {\n            start\n            end\n            __typename\n          }\n          closeDate {\n            start\n            end\n            __typename\n          }\n          temporaryCloseDate {\n            start\n            end\n            __typename\n          }\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      yogiyo {\n        businessHours {\n          actualDeliveryTime {\n            start\n            end\n            __typename\n          }\n          bizHours {\n            start\n            end\n            __typename\n          }\n          __typename\n        }\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    nlu {\n      ...NluFields\n      __typename\n    }\n    brand {\n      name\n      isBrand\n      type\n      menus {\n        order\n        id\n        images {\n          url\n          desc\n          __typename\n        }\n        name\n        desc\n        price\n        isRepresentative\n        detailUrl\n        orderType\n        catalogId\n        source\n        menuId\n        nutrients\n        allergies\n        __typename\n      }\n      __typename\n    }\n    optionsForMap @include(if: $isBounds) {\n      maxZoom\n      minZoom\n      includeMyLocation\n      maxIncludePoiCount\n      center\n      spotId\n      __typename\n    }\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n\nfragment RestaurantItemFields on RestaurantSummary {\n  id\n  dbType\n  name\n  businessCategory\n  category\n  description\n  hasBooking\n  hasNPay\n  x\n  y\n  distance\n  imageUrl\n  imageUrls\n  imageCount\n  phone\n  virtualPhone\n  routeUrl\n  streetPanorama {\n    id\n    pan\n    tilt\n    lat\n    lon\n    __typename\n  }\n  roadAddress\n  address\n  commonAddress\n  blogCafeReviewCount\n  bookingReviewCount\n  totalReviewCount\n  bookingReviewScore\n  bookingUrl\n  bookingBusinessId\n  talktalkUrl\n  options\n  promotionTitle\n  agencyId\n  businessHours\n  microReview\n  tags\n  priceCategory\n  broadcastInfo {\n    program\n    date\n    menu\n    __typename\n  }\n  michelinGuide {\n    year\n    star\n    comment\n    url\n    hasGrade\n    isBib\n    alternateText\n    __typename\n  }\n  broadcasts {\n    program\n    menu\n    episode\n    broadcast_date\n    __typename\n  }\n  tvcastId\n  naverBookingCategory\n  saveCount\n  uniqueBroadcasts\n  isDelivery\n  markerLabel @include(if: $isNmap) {\n    text\n    style\n    __typename\n  }\n  imageMarker @include(if: $isNmap) {\n    marker\n    markerSelected\n    __typename\n  }\n  isTableOrder\n  isPreOrder\n  isTakeOut\n  bookingDisplayName\n  bookingVisitId\n  bookingPickupId\n  popularMenuImages {\n    name\n    price\n    bookingCount\n    menuUrl\n    menuListUrl\n    imageUrl\n    isPopular\n    usePanoramaImage\n    __typename\n  }\n  visitorReviewCount\n  visitorReviewScore\n  detailCid {\n    c0\n    c1\n    c2\n    c3\n    __typename\n  }\n  streetPanorama {\n    id\n    pan\n    tilt\n    lat\n    lon\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n\nfragment NluFields on Nlu {\n  queryType\n  user {\n    gender\n    __typename\n  }\n  queryResult {\n    ptn0\n    ptn1\n    region\n    spot\n    tradeName\n    service\n    selectedRegion {\n      name\n      index\n      x\n      y\n      __typename\n    }\n    selectedRegionIndex\n    otherRegions {\n      name\n      index\n      __typename\n    }\n    property\n    keyword\n    queryType\n    nluQuery\n    businessType\n    cid\n    branch\n    franchise\n    titleKeyword\n    location {\n      x\n      y\n      default\n      longitude\n      latitude\n      dong\n      si\n      __typename\n    }\n    noRegionQuery\n    priority\n    showLocationBarFlag\n    themeId\n    filterBooking\n    repRegion\n    repSpot\n    dbQuery {\n      isDefault\n      name\n      type\n      getType\n      useFilter\n      hasComponents\n      __typename\n    }\n    type\n    category\n    __typename\n  }\n  __typename\n}\n"
```

Also, your booleans are actually strings, you need to define them like this:

```py
'variables': {
  'input': {
    ...
    'isNmap': False,
    ...
  },
  'isBound': True,
  'isNmap': False
}
```

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Hmm it returns me an Internal Server Error. ‘$isNmap’ and ‘$isBounds’ wasn’t provided with ‘Boolean!’ I’m not sure what this means, but I’m really confused because I’ve inserted boolean values in each inside the data parameter. I’m not sure how graphql works but it’s calling from a lot of .js when I took a glimpse at the Initiators.

Comment: I've tried out your recommendations, and I think we are almost there. But I still can't get the data so I posted a json I received below.